# Why does Prolog rule sometimes return False with similar inputs?

Tags: prolog, prolog-toplevel

I cannot understand why `false` is returned for `jordan` but not for `china`:

When I query:

```
countries_visited(jordan, X).
```

I get a return of `amman` and `false`.

But when I query

```
countries_visited(china, X).
```

I get a return of `beijing` and `shanghai`.

```
city_in_country(amman, jordan).    
city_in_country(shanghai, china).    
city_in_country(beijing, china).    
city_in_country(brussels, belgium).    
city_in_country(london, uk).    
city_in_country(manchester, uk).

city_visited(amman).    
city_visited(beijing).    
city_visited(shanghai).    
city_visited(cairo).    

countries_visited(ThisCountry, ThisCity) :- 
    city_visited(ThisCity), 
    city_in_country(ThisCity, ThisCountry).
```

Comment: In one word: [backtracking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backtracking)

Comment: In Prolog, if the logic indicates there *may* be more solutions (*i.e.*, there's a choice point), Prolog will backtrack looking for more. If it finds no more, it ultimately fails to do so (and outputs `false`). Your `countries_visited(jordan, X).` query is one of those cases. After finding `X = amman`, Prolog looks for more solutions and finds none, so it then says `false`. In the case of your query `countries_visited(china, X).` it does the same thing after finding the two solutions, at least when I tried it. I got `X = bejing` then `X = shanghai`, then `false.

Comment: This called a spurious choice point. They're pretty common, usually nothing to be alarmed about. They don't indicate an error or a mistake.

Comment: @Dan: leftover choicepoint

Comment: Hmm. That is interesting. I was using swish.swi-prolog.org and my results were inconsistent. It makes sense now you mention backtracking, but my inconsistent results are still baffling.